# C# : the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, api, server, httpwebrequest, rest

I'm working with the APIs on which I have to send a request to get an authentication key. I tried many way but always I'm getting the same exception as follows:

> the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send.

Here is my code for reference:

```
 public AuthTokenReponse GetAuthToken(IClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Info($"Getting Authentication Token");
                var client = new RestClient(_portalConfiguration.ApiAuthHostUrl);
                client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                request.AddHeader("client_id", clientConfiguration.ApiClientId);
                request.AddHeader("client_secret", clientConfiguration.ApiClientSecret);

                request.AddHeader("Gstin", clientConfiguration.ApiGstin);
                request.AddHeader("user_name", clientConfiguration.ApiUserName);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

                var obj = new AuthRequestDto();
                var appKey = GenerateAppKey();

                obj.Data = new AuthRequestDto.DataDto
                {
                    UserName = clientConfiguration.ApiUserName,
                    Password = EncryptAsymmetric(clientConfiguration.ApiPassword, clientConfiguration.ApiPublicKey),
                    AppKey = Encrypt(appKey, clientConfiguration.ApiPublicKey),
                    ForceRefreshAccessToken = true
                };


                request.AddJsonBody(new
                {
                    data = obj.Data
                });

                _logger.Error($"Request Json : {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)}");


                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                //Here I'm getting the error in my Log file.
                _logger.Error($"Response Error {response.ErrorMessage}");
                _logger.Error($"Response Content {response.Content}");

                if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthTokenReponse>(response.Content);

                    if (result.Status > 0)
                    {
                        result.SekToken = DecryptBySymmetricKey(result.Data.Sek, appKey);

                        return result;
                    }
                    _logger.Error($"Error while getting auth token {response.Content} {response.StatusCode}");
                }
                else if (response != null)
                {
                    _logger.Error($"Error while getting auth token {response.Content} Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Error($"Error while getting auth token {response.Content} , Reason unknown.");

                }



                return null;

            }
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error while getting auth token", ex);

                return null;
            }

        }
```

Options I have already tried:

1. Clearing Caches
2. Adding SecurityProtocols

If you have any solution then please let me know.

Comment: Try removing : SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11.  TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are no long allowed and may cause and exception.

Comment: @jdweng Tried, but not working

Comment: The error does not look like an authentication error.  Get the status code.  If you are getting a status code then it means the authentication completed and the server did not like a setting in the post.  Add :  _logger.Error($"Response Status Code {response.StatusCode}");

Comment: Status code is showing as 0

Comment: How long does it take for failure to occur?  If a proxy is not found a 30 second timeout will occur.  if error occurs sooner than a proxy was found.  Check encryption key in certificate and see if it is valid for TLS 1.2/1.3 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  What kernel/operating system are you using?  The kernel may be old and doesn't support TLS 1.2/1.3

Comment: it takes almost a 30 seconds, I didn't calculated exactly but it fails on same interval every time I send a request

Comment: @jdweng Actually app is hosted on client's server (Windows Server 2012) I didn't have much info about the kernal version and also I don't have full access to the client's server

Comment: It looks like the proxy server is not being found.  Do you need a proxy?  To disable proxy set to null : client.Proxy = null;

Comment: @jdweng tried  by making client.Proxy = null, but didn't work

Comment: I was referring to the client operating system, not the server.  You are using CORE which is used on devices.  The server should support 1.2/1.3.

Comment: @jdweng Client is using the Windows Server 2012. I'm sending the request directly from his server, not from the other system.

Comment: TLS both the server and client need to support 1.2/1.3.  Doesn't matter which end starts the connection.  So I think in this case you have a 2012 Server as the client (make the request) and a device/phone as the server getting the request and replying with a response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223817/discussion-between-okasha-momin-and-jdweng).

Comment: @jdweng I just checked the registry of the client's server, and there is only one protocol registered as SSL 2.0 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

should I add a key for TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine, there was a restriction to the client's server that every IP used in calling the API, need to be registered on their portal. The error was raising because IP was not registered.

So if anyone face the similar issue, then please try this solution too.